# How can restrict data from an Included class with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have two classes that are used by ASP.NET Identity. One is the backing class for a list of users and the other has roles. In the database there are three tables. AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles. Because of the way they are mapped in Entity Framework these three are mapped to just two classes:

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new List<AspNetUserClaim>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new List<AspNetUserLogin>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new List<AspNetRole>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class AspNetRole
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can create a LINQ statement that retrieves all of the users that have a certain role type or if I supply a roleId of zero then I want to see all users and not restrict on the roleId.  Here is what I tried:

```
        var user = await db.AspNetUsers
            .Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.SelectMany(r => r.Id == roleId || roleId == 0))
            .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles);
```

I also tried:

```
        var user = await db.AspNetUsers
            .Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.Select(r => r.Id == roleId || roleId == 0))
            .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles);
```

Comment: parameter for `Where` is a func that need return `bool`, so you can try `.Where(u =>roleId == 0 || u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId))` or something like this

Comment: can you please put this as an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameter for [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) is

> predicate
>   Type: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>
>   A function to test each element for a condition.

so you need pass a function that return `bool` like

```
.Where(u => roleId == 0 //if roleId is 0 return all
         || u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId) // check that user have any roles with id equals to roleId
      )
```